# mysql play crazy with pymysql

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python, pymysql

I've something very strage with mysql 5.5, python 2.7, pymysql, os x 10.6.8

I've a mysql table id, name, fuzzy. I've generated a python list like

```
cursor.execute('select id, SOUNDEX(name) from categorie')

result = [i for i in cursor.fetchall()]
```

then I want update the fuzzy field:

```
for i in result:
    try:
       cursor.execute("""update categorie set fuzzy='%s' where id='%s' % (i[1], i[0]))
    except pymysql.MySqlError, e:
       print e
```

after I execute the code I receive any error, that does mean for me, the query has been execute succesfuly, insted no. No change has happened in the DB, but the most curious thing is that after the python code execute, the Mysql server doesn't execute any update query anymore from any kind of client:

Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

I'm only able to execute select query succesfuly.
Practically a must restart the mysql server and only then the update query are execute successfuly, but as soon as I run the python query-code the play start again.

I tried this on a mysql server on a window machine too with the same results.
I also tried to change the pymysql with MySqlDb also whith the same results.

Comment: It's not totally clear from your question whether your `for i in result:` loop completes, or whether things get hung up while the loop is in progress.  You may wish to put a `START TRANSACTION` SQL command before the loop and a `COMMIT` command after it finishes.

Comment: By the way, it's helpful on Stack Overflow if you accept the answers to your questions that help you. Visit the correct answer and click on the green check box.

Comment: thks. that helped. Where are the correct answers? Post a link because I can't find one.